# Счетчик в Stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

имеется следующий код:

```
addList.stream().filter(x -> x.startsWith(contact)).*;
```

как мне вывести число итераций удовлетворивших данному условию?

Answer (score 0):

тыкался тыкался и натыкал =)

```
 int count = (int) addList.stream().filter(x -> x.startsWith(contact)).count();
```